# Android notification - custom inboxstyle (add line )

Tags: android, notifications, customization

I'd like to create a create expandable notification, in the pretty much gmail-like style. In general, using NotificationCompat.InboxStyle would be enough. But i need to add an icon in each line. Pretty much like Whatsapp do.
See the screenshot
[image]
Any ideas how to implement it? Besides custom layout with RemoteViews

Comment: That looks like an emoji to me. See if you're able to use unicode of an emoji in notification text.

Comment: Ain't working. Seems like inboxstyle doesn't support unicode emojis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly wrote some poor code and I have emojis everywhere.

```
String emoji = new String(Character.toChars(0x1F60A));
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("5 New mails from " + emoji)
            .setContentText(emoji)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle()
                    .setBigContentTitle(emoji)
                    .addLine(emoji)
                    .addLine(emoji)
                    .setSummaryText(emoji))
            .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, noti);
```