# Images are shown as '[OBJ]' in notification lines

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I've been trying to add an image from `drawable` folder into a notification line. But the image doesn't appear and `[OBJ]` is shown instead.

I can add image in any other place on notifications. Also I can add `emoji` into a notification line like this issue [Android notification - custom inboxstyle (add line )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38609148/3765109) .

But I can not add an image.

Is there any chance to overcome this issue?

```
public void someMethod() {
    ...
    mInboxStyle.addLine(imageSpanned());
    ...
}


private Spanned imageSpanned () {
    String imgString = "Something <img src=\"ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp\">";
    return Html.fromHtml(imgString, mImageGetter, null);
}


Html.ImageGetter mImageGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable drawable;
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        int drawableId = res.getIdentifier(source, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
        drawable = res.getDrawable(drawableId);
        int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();   
        int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        return drawable;
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: Lol, you deleted my comment. You can't load images in this way. Using method `getIdentifier()` will provide you a drawable id when you don't know it, you know just name. In this manner you can't load images, that's way is displayed `OBJ`. Also is `OBJ` because `Html` can't load that image.

Comment: :) Actually I'd tried to take the question at the top. So is there any other way to load images?

Comment: Also I tried `Base64` string for an `svg` too. But I never try `Base64` together with a `png` file.

Comment: You can try  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context.getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

Comment: @SagarPujari the question is not about `setSmallIcon()` method. Indeed about `setContent(IMG must be over here)`. Thanks anyway..

Comment: `I'd tried to take the question at the top` I don't think that you are allowed to pop your question by deletting the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp` icon resource in your `drawables` or `mipmap`.

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append("Something").append(" ");
builder.setSpan(
       new ImageSpan( 
            getActivity(), 
            R.drawable.ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp), 
            builder.length() - 1,  
            builder.length(),  
           0
       ));

textView.setText(builder);
```

Comment: I'm trying.. I should provide a source string instead of `R.drawable.ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp` because of working on a `React-Native` project :)

Comment: You didn't specify that you working in react. In this case i don't know how to help you.

Comment: Hey thank you again :) But i'm novice on Android development. I wonder that what does `idk` stand for? Is `sdk`?

Comment: "I don't know", sorry for that.

Comment: OK. I'll overcome it. And then I'd accept your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Unfortunately. I've tried `Bitmap` instead of source string but it doesn't work for me. I use API 23. Again, thank you for taking your time.